# Why is CodeBlocks not working properly?

Tags: codeblocks

[image: codeblocks]

here, i cant open the main.c file which is supposed to be under the title print.
where did it disappear?

---

Comment: is it a console application project?

Comment: yes.it is a console appplication project.

Comment: please check it in saved location whether it is exist .

Comment: Without very detailed records of your recent actions no-one can know
why `main.c` is *supposed* to be there. Please describe steps by
which some problem can be reproduced.